# SQL Date format with HTML output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a date & time stored in a table. One column (`moddate`) is in `datetime` format but unfortunately, the time is recorded in another column (`modtime`) which is `varchar(8)`. This can't be changed. All the `datetime` rows have `00:00:00` as the time. I want to join these columns together to achieve something like `05/07/2017 16:54`, which seems to work when I select within SSMS.

Example output from SSMS

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
|             Description              |    Code1     |  Code2   |      Date Modified      | Modified By |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
| Other Costs & Benefits - Other Costs | 70-0-1-04-00 | 70010400 | 2017-07-05 16:54:00.000 | dave        |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

When I output to HTML, it shows as `2017-07-05T00:00:00` (Notice the `T` in the middle), without the time column. I get the same result if I only select the `datetime` column.

[image: Incorrectly displayed dates in HTML format]

Here is my code to output to HTML and email.

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;  

SET @tableHTML =  
    N'<H2>Title</H2>' +  
    N'<table border="1">' +  
    N'<tr><th>Description</th><th>Code 1</th>' +  
    N'<th>Code 2</th><th>Date Modified</th><th>Modified by</th>' +  
    N'</tr>' +  
    CAST ( ( select
      td = [des], '',
       td = [maskednum], '',
      td = [num], '',
       td = [moddate] + ' ' + [modtime], '',
       td = [moduser], '' 
      from galtable
       where [moddate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  
    N'</table>' ;  

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='emailaddresshere@email.com',  
    @subject = 'Subject',  
    @body = @tableHTML,  
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

The script to create the table is unremarkable and the only lines of interest are:

```
[moddate] [datetime] NULL,
[modtime] [varchar](8) NULL,
```

My question is: How come it's not displaying my date & time correctly in the HTML output and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your time string is formatted as `HH:MM:ss`, then the following will give you the date along with the time in a DATETIME:

```
[moddate]+CAST([modtime] AS DATETIME)
```

Use that expression where you expect the date and time in one field.

If the value is supposed to be read by humans in a specific format, you can use the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function. This would give you `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[moddate]+CAST([modtime] AS DATETIME),120)
```

Or you can use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function for more precise formatting (for SQL Server 2012+). E.g.

```
FORMAT([moddate]+CAST([modtime] AS DATETIME),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
```

Would give you the formatting in your question.

Comment: This works better but I am still getting a `T` in the middle of the date. Like this: `2017-07-05T16:54:00`

Comment: @JayF1 The T is part of the ISO 8601 format for a date/time. Is that value supposed to be read by humans or by computers?

Comment: Humans are reading the email, so ideally I'd like the `T` to go away!

Comment: @JayF1 Your SQL Server version (2005) doesn't allow the use of the FORMAT function, which is a drag. You'll have to format it by hand if you strictly want it in the format in your question. Even the DAY, MONTH, YEAR, etc functions are 2008+, which makes formatting even more cumbersome.

Comment: Yeah, that really sucks. It is one of our legacy systems, unfortunately. I'll see if I can figure out how to format it manually.

Answer (score 0):

`@moddate + ' ' + @modtime` results in a `datetime` type so is serialized accordingly (in ISO8601 format - hence the `T`).

If you want a different format you need to explicitly convert into a string:

```
td = convert(varchar(19), @moddate + ' ' + @modtime, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround but you could use this:

```
select '<tr>'+ convert(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 121) +'</tr>'
```

EDIT:
Could not replicate the problem. I also added casts (was not sure what data type where were supposed to be):

```
declare @galtable table ([des]varchar(10) DEFAULT '', [maskednum]varchar(10) DEFAULT '', [num]varchar(10) DEFAULT '', [moddate] date DEFAULT cast(getdate() as date), [modtime] time DEFAULT cast(getdate() as time), [moduser]varchar(10) DEFAULT '')
insert into @galtable ([deS]) select '1'
declare @tableHTML varchar(max)
SET @tableHTML =  
    N'<H2>Title</H2>' +  
    N'<table border="1">' +  
    N'<tr><th>Description</th><th>Code 1</th>' +  
    N'<th>Code 2</th><th>Date Modified</th><th>Modified by</th>' +  
    N'</tr>' +  
    CAST ( ( select top 1
      td = [des], '',
       td = [maskednum], '',
      td = [num], '',
       td = cast([moddate] as varchar(20)) + ' ' + cast([modtime] as varchar(20)), '',
       td = [moduser], '' 
      from @galtable
       where [moddate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ) +  
    N'</table>' ;  

print @tableHTML
```

result was:

```
<H2>Title</H2><table border="1"><tr><th>Description</th><th>Code 1</th><th>Code 2</th><th>Date Modified</th><th>Modified by</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td/><td/><td>2017-09-18 16:02:01.5200000</td><td/></tr></table>
```

Comment: Close, but I get a duplicate time - `Jul 5 2017 12:00AM 16:54`

Comment: Ah, fixed it now with `varchar(11)` instead of 20